# How to determine Linux kernel image name in u-boot?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

I am currently loading my kernel image `uImage`, stored into a dedicated mmc partition, using fat commands. It works as expected while I am loading the kernel by giving its name :

```
fatload mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} uimage-1.bin
```

I would like to support more than one variant of the device using same bootloader. It implies different kernel names.

So, could it be possible to use the first kernel (*.bin extension) found in the partition instead of using an hardcoded value ?

Comment: Sure, it might be possible to do a lot of things using `fatls` and scripts if you've built U-Boot with the hush shell.  If the kernel was stored in an ext4 filesystem, then the simpler route is to use symbolic links.

Comment: @sawdust thank for your answer ! What do you mean by using symbolic links ? Kernel is stored in an `fat` filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to choose a kernel is by providing as script named boot.scr or boot.scr.uimg. If U-Boot is compiled with CONFIG_DISTRO_DEFAULTS=y it will automatically execute the script.